# Grails Hanging on 'Configuring classpath'

Tags: eclipse, maven, grails

I know similar questions have been asked but I've been quite thorough looking through them.

I downloaded the ggts bundle and used Eclipse to create a project called GrailsExample. When I try to run the groovy app it hangs on 'Refresh Dependencies (33%)'. The last log output is 'Configuring classpath'. The same happens when I run ANY grails command from the DOS prompt.

I am behind a firewall. When I try to use the 'grails add-proxy' command, it hangs on the same step.

I changed the logging level to be verbose, and nothing changed.

I commented out some of the repositories from my BuildConfig.groovy file, same problem.

I tried running grails clean --offline, that also hangs on the same point.

I tried commenting out a couple of the repositories (see below)

When I run 'grails clean -offline --stacktrace' I get the following error:

```
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1
| Error Required Grails build dependencies were not found. This is normally due to internet connectivity issues (such as a misconfigured proxy) or missing repositories in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy. Please verify your configuration to continue.
```

I don't know what to do now. I'm stuck just like grails.

My BuildConfig.groovy below

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "verbose" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        //grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        //grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you type the complete command as `grails add-proxy client --host=proxy-server --port=nnnn` ? Assuming you have the correct values for your proxy. Check the oficial grails reference http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0/ref/Command%20Line/set-proxy.html

Comment: Yes. I tried that from the command line a few different ways and each time it hangs after printing 'Configuring Classpath'.

Comment: ARGHHH, Figured it out!! If I run that command while in a folder that contains a grails project, it hangs and blows up. I needed to run 'add-proxy' in a generic folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out after the prompting from Salvador. I ran create-app originally and stepped into that folder. It was at that point I tried to run the 'add-proxy' command. It kept hanging and eventually blowing up with the 'xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1' error mentioned above.

You need to run this command outside of a project folder. It appears the actions taken after 'Configuring Classpath' varies depending on the folder context you're in.